# difference between "was always been" vs "It has always been"

Tags: sentence-construction

It there a difference between these sentences?

> It **was** always been my intention to play for  for Team GB

vs

> It **has** always been my intention to play for  for Team GB

Comment: Why do you have "for for" in both examples?

Comment: What structure do you think "was been" is?

Answer (score 1):

The “was been” option is ungrammatical, no two ways about it. You could grammatically say “It always was my intention.” The “has been” option is definitely grammatical.

A primary auxiliary verb consisting of a form of “be” coupled with a past participle indicates the passive voice of the verb specified by the past participle. Intransitive verbs like “be” have no passive voice.

A primary auxiliary verb consisting of a form of “have” coupled with a past participle indicates a perfect tense of the verb specified by the past participle. All verbs except modals have perfect tenses.

This is one of the most important rules of English grammar.

**EDIT** Yes, it is possible to have perfect tenses in the passive voice.

> It has been thought about many times before.

is an example. Here two past participles are used. A form of “have” plus “been” plus the past participle of the verb with substantive meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> It was always my intention to play for Team GB

This sentence uses [past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/past-continuous-and-past-simple). It describes an intention that started a long time ago and finished before now. It would be appropriate if the speaker is currently playing for Team GB, so the period of intent is in the past.

> It has always been my intention to play for Team GB

This sentence uses [present perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect). It describes an intention that started a long time ago and is still current.  It would be appropriate if the speaker is not yet playing for Team GB, or has only just been selected.

Note: I have corrected a couple of grammatical/typograhic errors in the two sentences